# To search the column title in the value (pos_tag value) of dataframe python and if it's matched put 1 else 0 as column value

Tags: python, design-patterns, matching

Dear Python community,

I am writing a python script to perform prediction using Naive Bayes, SVM, and Decision Tree supervised learning. I already completed all the data preprocessing until getting the prediction from the data that I have.

However, there is a need to add a few new columns (name, value) in the data frame as below.
[image]

My issue is I need to check if the column name (e.g. excellent, strip, male) exists in the pos_tag_noun's value, the value in those new columns set to 1, else put 0 as shown below.

[image]

I have been working for two days to resolve this issue but still not able to have a solution for it.

Really appreciated for help if any idea or solution to resolve my issue.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: are the new columns you're trying to add/populate fixed, or are you trying to create new columns from the values in `pos_tag_noun`? For example, do you also need a `bath` column? If you had another row with `('female', 'NN')`, would you want a `female` column?

Comment: Sorry to make you confused, I have updated the table above. so whatever the values from the pos_tag_noun, they will be populated as new columns and compare against the value of pos_tag_noun and set to 1 if exists else 0. Actually I have done on the populating these new columns. The only problem that I have is how to compare/check them against the value of pos_tag_noun.

Comment: If you can, please update your question with your tables in some sort of text format instead of a picture so others can more easily import them. Also, this is a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Yes, this is a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

This should work okay. The idea is to `explode` your values, `get_dummies`, and then `concat` back into your dataframe.

```
pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df['pos_tag_noun'].apply(lambda x: [item[0] for item in x]).explode()).groupby(level=-1).max()], axis=1)

                            pos_tag_noun  bath  excellent  hang  male  strip
0                      [(excellent, NN)]     0          1     0     0      0
1  [(strip, NN), (bath, NN), (hang, NN)]     1          0     1     0      1
2                           [(male, NN)]     0          0     0     1      0
```

If you don't want to use a lambda function + explode, you can replace it with something like `pd.DataFrame(df['pos_tag_noun'].to_list()).stack()`.